# How can the subobject fibration be obtained from the codomain fibration

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal A$ is category with pullbacks. Consider the codomain fibration $F : \mathcal A^\to \to \mathcal A$ and the restriction $F' : \mathcal{A}^\to_{\operatorname{Mon}} \to \mathcal A$ on the full subcategory of monos of $\mathcal A$.

> Is there are neat description / construction of $F'$ in terms of $F$ of some 'fibrational' construction that 'immediately' shows that $F'$ is a fibration too?

(in the 'immediately' part we can assume something like "monos are stable under pullbacks")

---

Motivation: One may want to replace "all monos" with "certain monos" and look, whether we still get a fibration.

Comment: ps : codomain is not really a fibration, only some codomain functors are, when A has all pullbacks.

Comment: @nicolas I assumed $\mathcal A$ has pullbacks.

Comment: I imagine so. but why not say "let's assume codomain is a fibration" if you want to introduce such hypothesis ?

Comment: @nicolas He literally said "Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a category with pullbacks" as the first sentence; this immediately implies that the codomain functor on $\mathcal{A}^\to$ is a fibration.

Comment: being VS having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One characterization is the following.

A monomorphism into an object $X$ inside a category $\mathcal C$ is (by definition) a subterminal object of the overcategory $\mathcal C/X$ (i.e. it admits at most one morphism from any other object in the fiber over $X$ of the codomain fibration). Since the codomain fibration is a bifibration i.e. since the pullback functors have left adjoints (post-composition functors), the pullback functors preserve limits and monomorphisms. In particular they preserve subterminal objects in the fibers, hence the subterminal objects in the fibers generate a full subfibration.

So one way to generalize to fibrations the statement that "monomorphisms are stable under pullback" is via the statement that the restriction of a fibration $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$ to the full subcategory $\mathcal M\hookrightarrow\mathcal F$ whose objects are the subterminal objects in fibers of $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$ is itself a fibration. In particular, this is the case if $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$ is a bifibration, and more generally if the pullback functors of $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$ preserve subterminal objects.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last sentence? I'm not familiar with (full) subfibrations and how they can be generated.

Comment: done, though i'm not saying anything deep there: just a full subcategory that happens to be closed under the pullbacks of the fibration (more precisely under the condition that if $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ is $p$-cartesian, then $Y$ in the full subcategory implies $X$ in the full subcategory).